# Want to extract Word which appears right ater "cta=" until the & sign in the URL

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I am using Google Data Studio and I just want to extract the word which appears right after `cta=` until `&` sign from the URLs (see below). Please see, the word `cta` might appear twice in the URL however I just want the first `cta` to be extracted.

I am currently using the following RegEx:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page, '((?i)cta=.*&+)')
```

which gives me the below result:

> cta=productpage-calculator-mobile-floating-personalloan&cta=productpage-calculator-mobile-floating-personalloan&

for the URL:

> /webforms/onlineform/personal-loan/web/personalloan.aspx?cta=productpage-calculator-mobile-floating-personalloan&cta=productpage-calculator-mobile-floating-personalloan&cta=productpage-calculator-mobile-floating-personalloan

How can I modify it to extract the word right after `cta=` until `&`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following pattern, along with a single capture group around what you actually want to match:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page, '(?i)cta=([^&]+)')
```

Check the link below for a working regex demo.

### Demo

The pattern works as follows:

```
(?i)cta=  match "cta=" in any case
([^&]+)  then match any number of characters following which are NOT &
         this captures everything until either the first & separator or the end of the URL
```